# System is out of GPU and shared host memory

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, modifiers, subdivision-surface

I am trying to render a displacement map in cycles. I want the output to be 5400x7200 pixels. While rendering at 100% I am always getting an 'Out of memory error. What is wrong with my model?

I have Nvidia GTX 1650 and 8GB RAM as system configuration.

**Output properties**
[image]

**Plane object properties**
[image]

**World sky texture settings**
[image]

**Modifier properties**
[image]

**Render properties**
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to render a gigantic image that requires a tremendous amount of computer memory. It is about 16GB just for the data.

So you need a graphics card with a lot of VRAM or **you can render it on CPU** (Cycles setting) when your computer has 32 GB RAM. Memory usage for the render below: Blender (20 GB) + Windows and browser = 29.9 GB.

When you don't have that much RAM you can split the image into tiles and move the camera for each tile. This should work because you use an orthographic camera.

[image: screenshot]